# MAMP - mysql server won't start on port 3306

Tags: mysql, mamp

mySQL Server refuses to start up on port 3306 but ok on 8889.

Anyone got any ideas?  Banging head on desk here :-)

Comment: What error gives? It sounds like the port 3306 is in use by another program (perhaps two mysql servers installed?)

Comment: check the server log for error.

Comment: seems to be the case that mysql is already running but killing in console doesn't help

Comment: As @Hemant_Negi says, check server log and see what happens

Comment: Ok What OS are you using

Comment: @Hemant_Negi MAMP = Mac Apache MySQL PHP...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be probably to figure out if there is another instance of MySQL running and stopping it, e.g. you could call in Terminal :

```
ps -ax | grep mysqld
```

and then kill the appropriate `mysqld` process.

And to check for processes listening on the port 3306 :

```
lsof -i:3306
```

Comment: checking server logs, then killing specific instance did the job. Thank your your contribution :-)

Answer (score 1):

for me solution was to stop mhsql service

```
sudo launchctl unload -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

and then reload it from MAMP